# How Can I Show a Thumb Drive Icon on the 19.10 Desktop?

Tags: icons, disk, drive

I tried using **Tweaks > Extensions**, but there is no **on/off** switch for drive icons.

Comment: Please be specific OS/release details (correct your question); Ubuntu desktop and server releases are *yy.mm* in format, and there was no release in 2019-January; thus it's likely you are running something currently unknown.

Comment: This answer is beyond comprehension.  I am running Ubuntu 19.1 PC desktop OS.  The general release, not a server release, and that's all I know.  Look for the forest, please, and don't let the trees distract you.

Comment: The majority of users who claim to be using 19.1 are actually using Mint or another non-Ubuntu distribution of GNU/Linux, and with there being no 2019-January release of Ubuntu, I don't know what you're running as no such release exists. The only way meaningful advice can offered is by avoiding guesses.  Mint uses run-time *adjustments* of Ubuntu packages thus effects differ..  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; except for specialist releases that only have a single release that use *yy* only.

Comment: I said Ubuntu 19.1, and that's exactly what I meant.  Why don't you take a nap and stop responding to this issue?  You are not helping!

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 19.1, your system is likely something else such as Linux Mint which has a 19.1 release. We need to know what you are running, and your system responds Ubuntu 19.1 then you have a forgery. All Ubuntu desktop & server releases use the *year.month* format of the initial release; thus it's a clue as to the software stack in use. You're answer implies you are off-topic (using a non-Ubuntu) or a using a forgery system in which case you should investigate what you're running as it's not Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll provide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases should you wish to check for yourself on Ubuntu releases.  If you scan for 19.1 you'll quickly see there is no such release, and the only 19.1 found is the 19.10 (2019-October standard release).  It's unsafe to provide advice when we don't know what you're using, especially as you've indicated it's something else (non-Ubuntu or a forgery and thus you need to investigate it)

Comment: I see the problem now.  I dropped the final zero because I thought the naming protocol was decimal, when actually it is as you say.  I'm running 19.10. I did find the flash drive icon over at the very bottom of the task bar (or whatever Ubuntu calls it) off the screen.